# Swift 2 arch4random

Tags: xcode, swift, arc4random

In my application, I use something like this to get random text on my label, except in my main `let randomNumber`code, in xCode, it has over 300 cases, to much to paste in here.:

```
let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(23))
var textLabel = "" as NSString
switch (randomNumber){
case 1:
    textLabel = "Kim."
    break
case 2:
    textLabel = "Phil."
    break
case 3:
    textLabel = "Tom"
    break
case 4:
    textLabel = "Jeff"
    break
default:
    textLabel = "Austin"
}
self.randomLabel.text = textLabel as String
```

But the problem is, that sometimes it shows the same text on the label 5-6 times, and other cases is not even used  yet, because it choose randomly. So how can I choose randomly, but if case example case 1 is already shown, it wont show up again, until all other cases has been shown.

Comment: When are you running the switch statement?

Comment: @DylanIreland - In the same function(?)

Comment: `var myNames = ["Kim.", "Phil.", "Tom", "Jeff", "Austin"]` **followed by line**
`let randomName = myNames.removeAtIndex(Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myNames.count-1))))`

Comment: @dfri Could you make a good answer for this one please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have an array of Names instead of a gigantic switch case:

```
var names = ["Kim.", "Phil.", "Tom", "Jeff", "Austin"] // and all your remaining names
let originalNames = names

func getRandomName() -> String {
    if (names.count == 0) {
        names = originalNames
    }
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(names.count)))
    return names.removeAtIndex(randomNumber)
}
```

This ensures every name gets printed before starting from the beginning again. The sample output is:

> Tom, Kim., Austin, Phil., Jeff

and then it starts again

> Austin, Jeff, Phil. ...

Finally put something like the following wherever it fits your need:

```
self.randomLabel.text = getRandomName()
```

Comment: Can i have a function with the whole array, and another function that only shows the first 3 names in the array?

Comment: @RoduckNickes don't know what you mean

Comment: Nvm.. Do i put the whole first code and the second code in a button action?

Comment: @RoduckNickes no, put the variables and the function in the class / on class level and the line for assigning the `text` into the button action

Comment: What am i supposed to do about this: http://s15.postimg.org/6o882c7nf/Screen_Shot_2015_12_25_at_22_02_00.png ?

Comment: @RoduckNickes put `var originalNames = [String]()` instead of `let originalNames = names` and put `originalNames = names` in the `viewDidLoad`

Comment: You are a lifesaver, thanks! Is there any other ways i can do this, because i also have an array with over 400 strings that has long sentence with up to 50 characters long, and that will use a lot of space in my .swift file.

Comment: @RoduckNickes well, you can try putting it into a file and reading that file, but that is entirely different topic, if you tried around with it you can of course ask a new question on SO.